# php. array_values function. how to get mapping from old keys to new keys?

Tags: php, arrays

There is function [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) in PHP such that

```
$array2 = array_values($array1);
```

`$array2` has the same values as `$array1` but keys are from 
`0` to `sizeof($array1) - 1`. Is it possible to get mapping from old keys to new keys?

EDIT. I will explain on an example:

```
$array1 = array( 'a' => 'val1', 'b' => 'val1');
$array2 = array_values( $array1 );
```

so now array2 has next values

```
$array2[0] = 'val1'
$array2[1] = 'val2'
```

How get array3 such that:

```
$array3['a'] = 0
$array3['b'] = 1
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by running this function but keeping the same keys?

Comment: Now there's many answers, but tbh, I still have absolutely no idea about what are you trying to do.

Comment: why down votes but no upvotes? good question

Comment: @capoluca: not even close to be called "good"

Comment: @capoluca that was a really, really bad question.

Comment: why? not clear what I want or not clear why I want it ( I did not try to explain why I want it)? But, I think, It is clear what does mapping from old key to new key.

Comment: @capoluca it was very unclear what you wanted. In fact, it seemed that you wanted what zerkms wrote. And now after you cleared that up, it's still a very simple question that you could easily have figured on your own with at least a minimal effort. That would be my explanation of the downvote.

Comment: @cypher no need to get hostile, if everyone could 'figure out' everything, this Q&A site wouldn't exist.

Comment: I would just like to say that putting why you want it is important, because someone might be able to do what you want in an easier/better way that you hadn't thought of yet. From what I read, it looks like you might be trying to do something in a complicated way (like looping through an assoc array with a for loop) that could be solved with something like `foreach($array1 as $key=>$value){ echo "{$key}=>{$value}\n"; }`.

Comment: @ddlshack I have absolutely nothing against well formed simple question which I don't think this is (was).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To produce a key map you need to first get the keys into a regular array and then flip the keys and values:

```
$array1_keymap = array_flip(array_keys($array1));
```

For example:

```
$array1 = array(
    'a' => 123,
    'b' => 567,
);

$array1_values = array_values($array1);
$array1_keymap = array_flip(array_keys($array1));
```

Value of `$array1_values`:

```
array(
    0 => 123,
    1 => 567,
);
```

Value of `$array1_keymap`:

```
array(
    'a' => 0,
    'b' => 1,
);
```

So:

```
$array1['a'] == $array1_values[$array1_keymap['a']];
$array1['b'] == $array1_values[$array1_keymap['b']];
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the easiest way.

Comment: OMG, you were right. How is it possible to get what he meant from his initial explanation?!?!??

Comment: Meh, @zerkms's solution still seems much simpler, I'd stick with that.

Comment: @zerkms Woohoo! I'm the mentalist!

Comment: Okay so maybe the question was unclear, but I don't think I deserve downvotes because of that.

Comment: @ddlshack: you - don't. And your only downvote wasn't by me. As a proof of that I'll upvote you in a moment

Comment: Thanks dude, I did not know array_flip function, exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as simple as

```
$array2 = $array1;
```

In this case you would get both values and keys like they are in the original array.

Comment: Oddly enough, this answer makes the most sense of all of these.

Comment: I really hope this was not meant as the question ;-)

Comment: @Jack: and I really hope this will teach OP how to ask questions ;-) So answered just for fun

Comment: He has two arrays, and wants to map the keys of the first to the keys of the second in an associative array.

Comment: @ddlshack that would be my guess as well; hmm, seems like a down vote swipe just came through this thread ;-)

Comment: The wrong answer gets upvoted and the correct ones get downvoted. Interesting.

Comment: @ddlshack what's interesting is that the question doesn't get down voted :)

Comment: @ddlshack: his second array is just a derivative from the first. There is no reason to prefer `array_value` + `array_keys` + `array_combine` over simply `=` in this case.

Comment: @Jack fixed ;-)
Btw given OP's style of thinking, I strongly suspect that what he need is something like [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php).

Comment: this answer is wrong, you cannot get keys of new array based on old one. Don't upvote it please

Comment: @capoluca: you need to ask better at first, not ask people to not upvote

Comment: I added example, should I explain more?

Comment: @capoluca: you added example after half an hour after original question. And according to your original question my answer was perfectly valid. So it's your fault, not mine

Comment: @zerkms I agree that Jack's solution is simpler that mine but both work, and this answer is wrong. And re your latest comment, I thought that what he was asking was clear. So did Jack obv.

Comment: @ddlshack: it's not my fault that OP asked not the thing he wanted to get

Comment: @zerkms but how your answer gives me a mapping? (just curious what question you wanted to answer)

Comment: @capoluca: it maps original keys to original values. You didn't elaborate enough what you mean by "map", and where and how it should be done.

Answer (score 1):

```
$keyMapping = array_combine(array_keys($array1), array_keys($array2));
```

This the keys of `$array1` and maps them to the keys of `$array2` like so

```
<?php
$array1 = array(
    'a' => '1',
    'b' => '2',
);

$array2 = array_values($array1);

print_r(array_combine(array_keys($array1), array_keys($array2)));

Array
(
    [a] => 0
    [b] => 1
)
```

Comment: Why did I get a downvote? I'm pretty sure this is what hes trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$array3 = array_keys($array1);
```

Now `$array3[$n]` is the key of the value in `$array2[$n]` for any `0 <= $n < count($array1)`. You can use this to determine which keys were in which places.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the same value of array1 but change the key to index numbers, try this:

```
$array2 = array();
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value){
$array2[] = $value;
// or array_push($array2, $value);
}
var_dump($array2);
```

Comment: Exactly the same as `array_values`